# Use Custom Image from URL in MapKit JS Annotation

Tags: javascript, mapkit-js

I'm working with MapKit JS for the first time and using the [Custom Callout example](https://developer.apple.com/maps/web/) from the Apple website. It uses the default red circle for the marker - I'd like to now change that to a custom image from a URL that I host but I'm having trouble updating the example to use a URL.

Here's the code from the Apple example that creates the Annotation:

```
    // Landmarks annotations
    var annotations = sanFranciscoLandmarks.map(function(landmark) {
      var annotation = new mapkit.MarkerAnnotation(landmark.coordinate, {
        callout: landmarkAnnotationCallout,
        color: "#c969e0"
      });
      annotation.landmark = landmark;
      return annotation;
    });
```

I'm trying to incorporate the example from the docs for [mapkit.ImageAnnotation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkitjs/imageannotation/2973888-mapkit_imageannotation):

```
    var coordinate = new mapkit.Coordinate(38.897957, -77.036560);

// The house logo is a white square.
// The image size is 32 x 32. Becuase the default anchor point is the bottom center
// of the image, offset the anchor by (0, -16) to make the center of the
// image the anchor point.
var houseOptions = {
    title: "The White House",
    subtitle: "1600 Pennsylvania Ave NW",
    url: { 1: "/images/house.png", 2: "/images/house_2x.png"},
    anchorOffset: new DOMPoint(0, -16)
};
var houseAnnotation = new mapkit.ImageAnnotation(coordinate, houseOptions);
map.addAnnotation(houseAnnotation);
```

but everything I've tried so far has failed. Is it possible to have a custom image URL that works with my existing code for the annotation?